# TypeError: Cannot find function forEach in object GmailMessage

Tags: google-apps-script

Using app script I'd like to get the most recent message in each thread and load it into an object for further filtering. So far I have:

```
var message_objs = []


// thread is a list of all email threads/chains. thread[i] is a specific email
for (i in threads) {
  var thread = threads[i]
  var messages = thread.getMessages()[0]; // get first message

        Logger.log(messages);


  messages.forEach(function(message){

    message_objs.push({
      'body': message.getPlainBody(),
      'date' : message.getDate(),
      'from' : message.getFrom(),
      'to' : message.getTo()



  });

    Logger.log(message_objs);
```

I'm running into the error in the title. The last 2 lines of the logs show:

```
[19-04-03 12:27:43:373 EDT] messages
[19-04-03 12:27:43:374 EDT] GmailMessage
```

What am I doing wrong? What is a better way to do this?

Comment: `thread.getMessages()[0]`

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

```
var messages = thread.getMessages()[0]; // get first message
Logger.log(messages);
messages.forEach(function(message){
```

To this:

```
var messages = thread.getMessages(); 
Logger.log(messages);
messages.forEach(function(message){
```